# How can i play videos from tomcat server path on web browsers or android?

Tags: java, android, video

I am using tomcat server and i am able to upload videos from my android device to my server but i am unable to play those videos in android not even in our web browsers by getting those videos path, how can i play videos from my server database on mobile browsers or web browsers?

Here i am able to display images by providing path from server but not working for videos

Answer (score 0):

You should give a look to MediaPlayer API of Android. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html

Internet is full of examples like this:

```
String vidAddress = "https://archive.org/download/ksnn_compilation_master_the_internet/ksnn_compilation_master_the_internet_512kb.mp4";
Uri vidUri = Uri.parse(vidAddress);
vidView.setVideoURI(vidUri);
vidView.start();
```

You can find more about that in this link:
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/streaming-video-in-android-apps--cms-19888